# VS setup project destroys self when installed files are deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, installation, vdproj

This should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it.  I have a setup project (VS2010) that packages a few dozen image files (along with my SQLite file) and copies them to the user's computer when the program is installed.  As these are essentially "stock" images, it's ok if the user deletes them (there is functionality to do so from within the program.)  However, after one or more of these images have been deleted,  the next time the program starts it gives a "Windows installer" dialog box, and deletes all of the remaining data files!

What I think is happening is the program sees the missing files, assumes the installation has been corrupted, and tries to go into some kind of recovery/uninstall mode.  I'd like to know how to indicate in the setup project that the files need to be installed, but may be removed by the user at any time.

I have tried several combinations of File properties, and nothing seems to do quite what I want, which is for my installer to put them where I say and never think about them again.  Do I have to reinvent the wheel and do this through a custom action??

EDIT: Transitive and Vital had both been set to True.  Setting them to False causes the program to re-add the deleted images back after it has been restarted!  I'll probably go with a custom action if I don't get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a file association or advertised shortcut Windows Installer automatically checks if [component key paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are missing. If a key path is not found, a repair is trigger to reinstall the component.

Most likely your installer repair process does something that removes the other files.

A solution is to not register your components with Windows Installer. This is done by using a null component GUID and it's not supported by Visual Studio setup projects (it is however supported by most of the other setup tools).

Another solution is to make sure that your image files are not key paths in their components. This is also not supported by Visual Studio.

If you want to use a setup authoring tool which offers more control, you can take a look at this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I know Visual Studio Setup projects aren't ideal (and won't even be supported in VS2012), but I'm committed at this point.  The hack that seems most appropriate for my needs is to have the installer put the files in the install directory, and then write a custom action to copy them to the user data directory, so Windows installer doesn't know about the ones in the data dir.

Again, I really appreciate your response, wasn't sure I was going to get a good answer to this one!